# Why is there a 1024 byte difference between each GPIO group in stm32?

Tags: stm32, gpio

Why is there a 1024 byte difference between each GPIO group in stm32?While the amount of register is only seven.Why there is so much space left?

[image]

Hope to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your microcontroller, the number of registers associated with a singular GPIO port is 7.
In my current project, the Microcontroller(STM32G0B1) has 11 different registers.
In more advanced Microcontrollers, it may be even more. To keep some kind of uniformity, they(the manufacturers like ST, TI, MM etc) keep these gaps in Addressing.